# Sonarqube src/test execution on version 7.6 with gradle

Tags: java, sonarqube

I am trying to analyze all of the java files located inside the src/test directory, but I can't get this working.

I have tried the options below

```
C:\Users\Test\SonarQube>gradle clean sonarqube -Dsonar.sources=src
```

Task :sonarqube FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':sonarqube'.
 File src/test/java/LibraryTest.java can't be indexed twice. Please check that
nclusion/exclusion patterns produce disjoint sets for main and test files

Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
ption to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

2) 
I have also tried with -Dsonar.sources=src/test -Dsonar.inclusions= src/**/*.java

```
C:\Users\Test\SonarQube>gradle clean sonarqube -Dsonar.sources=src
/test -Dsonar.inclusions= src/**/*.java
```

Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes=""

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Task 'src/**/*.java' not found in root project 'SonarQube'.
- Try:
  Run gradle tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option
  to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output
  . Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s

3)

```
C:\Users\Test\SonarQube>gradle clean sonarqube -Dsonar.sources=src
/test -Dsonar.inclusions=src/test/*.java
```

Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes=""

> Task :test
>   Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes=""
>
> Task :sonarqube
>   Failed to set working directory hidden: C:\Users\Test\SonarQube\build\sonar
>   SCM provider autodetection failed. Please use "sonar.scm.provider" to define SCM
>    of your project, or disable the SCM Sensor in the project settings.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 10s
5 actionable tasks: 5 executed

But still, I can't see changes on sonarqube server